# Running setup and cleanup scripts in Resharper for MSTest

Tags: unit-testing, mstest, resharper-6.0

I have tests running with MSTest. I use the .testsettings to run setup and cleanup scripts, needed to execute tests well.

We recently bought licenses for Resharper, and I'm trying to run the same tests using the test sessions in Resharper.
Unfortunately,m most of them fail because setup and cleanup scripts are not executed correctly.
For each script the path is relative to the location of the .testsettings file, and in resharper I configured tests to run from that directory.

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Does this help? http://www.sds-consulting.com/blog/resharper-test-runner-and-mstest-projects Have you named the settings file "Resharper.testsettings"?

Comment: Not that name, but the article explicitly tells that the name is only an example.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your .testsettings dependencies and let your tests set up their dependencies in code. Resharper testrunner, and your tests in general, works better if everything is done in code.